# Using Azure IoT Edge On A Raspberry Pi (with Windows 10 IoT) and TI Sensor Tag using BLE protocol to Forward Messages To IoT Hub

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub, thingworx

I want to use Use Azure IoT Edge On A Raspberry Pi (loaded with Windows 10 IoT Core) that collects data from a TI Sensor Tag using BLE protocol to Forward Device To Cloud Messages To IoT Hub.

Eventually I would like to use ThingWorx as the IoT hub via MQTT protocol or just use ThingWorx Edge SDKs and WebSocket-based Edge MicroServer on the client.

So basically I want to know how to pump data I collect via the Tag Sensor on Raspberry Pi that runs .net code and push it to an Iot hub as well as receive some messages from the cloud to device (like turn off temperature sensor). I am a c#.net developer and I a looking for sample projects, articles, guides, videos that will help me start IoT development

IoT Edge BLE sample at this link [Use a physical device with Azure IoT Edge | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-iot-edge-physical-device) shows how to send messages using Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian.

**In the above article them mentioned: "At the time of writing (06/12/2017), IoT Edge only supports BLE modules in gateways running on Linux."**

I was wondering if IoT Edge only supports BLE modules is now available in Windows 10 IoT Core.

Thank  you,
Rad

**Update: I think I found something. If data can be collected as described, then additional code using Azure IoT Edge SDK needs to be written to send messages to IoT hub. Can somebody confirm if I am on the right track?**

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Samples/BLEGatt
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Samples/BLEGatt2

Comment: There are two questions here: how to get data from the sensor and how to send the data to Azure IoT. You can actually write a special program that will do both. I never worked with Azure Edge but worked with Azure IoT. In our case there were people who wrote the program to send the data to Azure IoT and they did not use Azure Edge. But they had some custom sensors that were actually analogue. No chance to connect them to Azure Edge. And Azure is cheaper than Thingworx and also more flexible in my opinion (I worked with both)

Comment: Thanks Keiv.Fly. My company will purchase ThingWorx. I just want to learn both platforms and try to stay with industry standard protocols.Can you see above update to see if I found a good material that will help me.

Comment: In IoT there is no industry standard protocol. Everything changes every year. In Azure IoT Hub we use REST API. We had a toy example with OPC UA and Thingworx, but never used it in production, probably because OPC UA is not that convenient. If I remember correctly in a Cumulocity project we use MQTT to send data to Cumulocity. I think the example that you found are good ones.

Comment: Since you had experience with both Azure and ThingWorx, If I choose MQTT protocol with Azure Edge client a ThingWorx connector for Azure IoT, will I loose any of the benefits that ThingWorx only solution provides regarding binding of properies, events and service. I mean can I combine Azure IoT client and ThingWorx server and still enjoy Thingworks modeling?

Comment: With thingworx I worked mainly with thingworx ML. On the level I worked I did not need something special. Only data from the system to analyse it. I do not know if you can combine. The thing is that it is easier to use either Azure or Thingworx. And Azure has everything you need. We created real-time forecasting using Azure with everything there. Dashboard is Power BI, data streaming is Stream Analytics, forecasting models in Azure ML. Analytics in Hadoop-Spark using files coming from the Hub. Thingworx server will be too expensive in Azure VM because Cassandra needs multiple fast servers.

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT Edge now supports Windows IoT Core. This improvement is part of the [public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-edge-open-for-developers-to-build-for-the-intelligent-edge/) of new features which concentrates on cloud configuration, deployment, and monitoring of AI to edge devices.

The internal architecture of IoT Edge has changed to support these features in an industry standard way. Primarily, modules are now implemented as containers. This change means that IoT Edge will not support Raspberry Pi 3 (ARM) running Windows IoT Core until Windows supports containers on ARM. [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-core) walks you through running IoT Edge on a MinnowBoard Turbot (x64) running Windows IoT Core.

IoT Edge does support ARM devices running Linux. [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-simulate-device-linux) walks you through running IoT Edge on a Raspberry Pi 3 (ARM) running Raspbian Jessie.

We do not yet have an equivalent tutorial for connecting a SensorTag through an IoT Edge device; however it is a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/907045-azure-iot-edge/suggestions/32308444-example-of-c-based-module-for-transparent-gateway) which is in our plan.